# Spring bean instantiation exception for collection

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

Spring is throwing the following exception when it tries to instantiate a bean which implements `AbstractSet<Channel>`.

> Cannot create copy of Collection type [org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup] - injecting original Collection as-is

```
<bean id="defaultChannelGroup" class="org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup" scope="prototype"></bean>

<bean id="client" class="com.menacheri.Client">
   <property name="id" value="6"></property>
   <property name="gameRoomChannelGroup" ref="defaultChannelGroup"></property>
</bean>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What type is the `gameRoomChannelGroup` property of `Client`?

Comment: Also, injecting a `prototype`-scoped bean into a singleton bean doesn't really make any sense... are you sure you mean to do this?

Comment: The type is "ChannleGroup". The interface is implemented by the defaultChannelGroup class. There are different types of client, each with its own instance of channelgroup. Hence the prototype. i have only shown one client definition in the config.

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.0.5 seems to have a bit better error messages, I can't find the one you've provided. Here are the possible reasons (errors from Spring sources):

- `Collection of type [] returned null Iterator`
- `Cannot access Collection of type [] - injecting original Collection as-is`
- `Cannot create copy of Collection type [] - injecting original Collection as-is`
- `Collection type [] seems to be read-only - injecting original Collection as-is`

Nevertheless, try wrapping the collection you are trying to inject in a new, fresh one, like this:

```
<bean id="wrappedSet" class="java.util.HashSet">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="defaultChannelGroup"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

...and inject `wrappedSet` instead. Might  help, just a guess.

Comment: The class definition of DefaultChannelGroup is like this 'public class DefaultChannelGroup extends AbstractSet<Channel> implements ChannelGroup'. I am using the ChannelGroup functionality in my class, hence injecting the wrappedset is not quite right for my case.

Comment: I tried with Spring 3.1 and got the following exception Cannot create copy of Collection type [org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup] - injecting original Collection as-is. @skaffman @Tomasz Nurkiewicz